# Very weird error 401?

Tags: c#, api, http-status-code-401

I am receiving a 401 error I am not anticipating. I am 100% sure the password and usernamne is correct. When I try the it on postman it works, and I get the data I expect. But in this code, the `.downloadstring()` method returns a 401 error. I created a new harvest account and tried get to that one with the same code, just changed the password and username and I got the API data I wanted. Is there any other reason then wrong password or username error 401 can be cached?

```
public List<Project> GetAllProjects()
{
    uri = "https://bruh.harvestapp.com/projects";
    jsonPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "projects.json");

    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword));

        string response = webClient.DownloadString(uri);

        projectsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Wrapper>>(response).Select(p => p.project).ToList();
    }

    return projectsList;
}
```

Comment: Iam using harvest api

Comment: You say "on Postman, works". Let me doubt that. Are you using Fiddler to check that the requests are 100% the same? I think the real problem is in the request headers.

Comment: You have problem in authorization. Did you check in which format does **HARVEST-API** accepts the header. Or are you sending the correct token(i.e. username:password)

Comment: Or may be ifyou are using BASIC authentication, it says **username + ":" + password** should be sent in the header

Comment: yes iam using the "username + ":" + password" format

Comment: I got it to work the problem was that the password contain a "§" sign in it which c# had problem reading... thanks anyways for your time

Comment: Answer your own question and accept that so tha the traffic does not get confused @RobelHaile

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/harvesthq/harvest_api_samples/blob/master/harvest_api_sample.cs) C# code sample from harvest, there are a few things that need to be changed:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  HttpWebRequest request; 
  HttpWebResponse response = null; 
  StreamReader reader; 
  StringBuilder sbSource; 
  // 1. Set some variables specific to your account.
  string uri = "https://yoursubdomain.harvestapp.com/projects";
  string username="youremail@somewhere.com";
  string password="yourharvestpassword";
  string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;

  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Validator;

try
  { 
     request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest; 
     request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
     request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

     // 2. It's important that both the Accept and ContentType headers are
     // set in order for this to be interpreted as an API request.
     request.Accept = "application/xml"; 
     request.ContentType = "application/xml"; 
     request.UserAgent = "harvest_api_sample.cs";
     // 3. Add the Basic Authentication header with username/password string.
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

     using (response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) 
     { 
        if (request.HaveResponse == true && response != null) 
        { 
           reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
           sbSource = new StringBuilder(reader.ReadToEnd());
           // 4. Print out the XML of all projects for this account.
           Console.WriteLine(sbSource.ToString()); 
        } 
     } 
  }
```